# echo fetch_array row if they have the same name

Tags: php, mysql, html

SOLVED: thanks to everyone for the fast answers

I have 3 tables, i joined them(checked in SQL and the values are right) but the problem is that 2 of them have the same field "denumire" with different values and i need to echo them

To be clearer this code is echoing the same value but in the mysql the ID's are right:

```
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row1[`specializare`.'denumire']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row1[`disciplina`.'denumire']) . "</td>";
```

mysql tables structure:

```
specializare->ID_specializare, denumire 
disciplina->ID_disciplina,denumire 
preda->ID_specializare, ID_disciplina, etc
```

sql_query in php:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT preda.ID_material, prof.ID_prof, prof.nume, prof.prenume, `specializare`.denumire, disciplina.denumire, preda.an_studiu, preda.semestru, preda.material
FROM `prof`
LEFT JOIN `preda` ON `prof`.ID_prof = `preda`.ID_prof
LEFT JOIN `specializare` ON `specializare`.ID_specializare= `preda`.ID_specializare
LEFT JOIN `disciplina` ON `disciplina`.ID_disciplina = `preda`.ID_disciplina
WHERE '".$_SESSION['ID_prof']."'=prof.ID_prof
ORDER BY specializare.denumire;");
```

Comment: take one of the fields that is a duplicate and use the `AS` syntax to give it a different name

Comment: so SELECT `specializare`.denumire, disciplina.denumire as disciplina.denumire2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases in your query

```
SELECT specializare.denumire as val1, disciplina.denumire as val2 etc .....
```

then do

```
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row1['val1'])
```

Answer (score 5):

When you run the SQL query, you should use an alias column name.

e.g.

```
SELECT t1.id as t1_id , t2.id as t2_id FROM table1 t1 , table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.table_id_match
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an alias on your tables and columns like this:

```
select
    a.someColumnName as aCol,
    b.someColumnName as bCol
from
    table1 a
        join table2 b
            on a.tableID=b.tableID
```

And use the a/b (or whatever alias you set on tables) to determine which columns and how you refer to them when you bring them in (by using the `as aCol`) in the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the column, you can an alias:

```
SELECT denumire AS specDenumire FROM specializare
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here we need to understand wts happening.

In mysql,
you might have overcome the conflict by tablename.columnname but the result given by mysql would be:
denumire | denumire instead of `specializare`.'denumire' | `disciplina`.'denumire'

So, whem php stores that result in array while using mysql_fetch_assoc(). since, the key is like they are overwritten i.e
$arr['denumire'] = 1 //`specializare`.'denumire' will be overwritten by
$arr['denumire'] = 2 //`disciplina`.'denumire'.
So, thus you solve by alias